# List from a Graph

Tags: julia

I have experienced with LightGraphs package in Julia and I have builded a random graph using erdos_renyi(n,p). I would like to know how can I generate a list of edges from this graph. For example:

If I do:

`p=erdos_renyi(3,3)`

I would like to have a function, which lists me the edges of this graph. That is to say:

`List(p)=[1,2],[2,3],[1,3]]`

Thank you so much for your collaboration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you should do just:

```
edges(p)
```

it will not create you a list of edges, but a lazy edge iterator. The reason why it is preferred is that the number of edges can be very large and it could use a lot of RAM.

If you need to have a vector of edges you can `collect` this iterator with:

```
collect(edges(p))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you know how to create the adjacency matrix from this collection?

Comment: Just do `adjacency_matrix(p)`. Is this enough for you?